# How to include a quotation mark in a text field from field calculator

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator

I'm trying to attribute pipe size and need to include a quotation mark in a text field.  How do I include that in the field calculator.  "4"" doesn't work.

Comment: Are you looking for a single quotation (') or a double quotation (") ?  and at the end or the start - or both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the Python parser:

```
"""4" """
```

or

```
"""4\""""
```

or

```
'4\"'
```

Comment: Option one works but leaves a space after the quote. Option two works, but why 3/4 quotes? 1/2 works for me. Option three also works, but why the \ as it works without that for me?

Answer (score 1):

1. Python parser `'4"'` (single numeral double single)
2. VB parser `"4''"` (double numeral single single double) - not really
   what you want, but a workaround from [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/48683/how-to-insert-a-quotation-mark-through-the-field-calculator-of-attribute-table-o), where it is
   also just suggested to do it with a label expression rather than in
   data