# QGIS 3x put apostrophe in the field calculator text

Tags: qgis, field-calculator

I want to put the street name in my field calculator.

The problem is, that it contains the apostrophe as per in the image below:

[image]

The expression becomes invalid.

Even if I try:

```
 "Christy's Yard"
```

or even

```
 ""Christy's Yard""
```

regarding to this thread

[How to insert a quotation mark through the Field Calculator of attribute table of a Shapefile?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/48683/how-to-insert-a-quotation-mark-through-the-field-calculator-of-attribute-table-o)

is still wrong.

Is there any way to include the apostrophe inside the field calculator text, which must be quoted?

Answer (score 5):

You just need to double the problematic apostrophe so the expression become :

```
'Christy''s Yard'
```

Answer (score 4):

Also you can escape the apostrophe with backslash `\`

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Try concatenating the phrase together using a `char` code:

`'Christy' || CHAR(39) || 's yard'`

EDIT: Yeah @J.R's answer is better, +1